# error: ‘struct msghdr’ has no member named ‘msg_iov’

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, unix-socket

I am writing unix socket in kernel module and when I try to compile, I get the following errors:

> error: ‘struct msghdr’ has no member named ‘msg_iov’
>
> error: ‘struct msghdr’ has no member named ‘msg_iovlen’

I try read the implementation of `msghdr` but I didn't find anything.

```c
ret = kernel_recvmsg(sock, msg, vec, BUFFER_SIZE, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);

msg_iov = msg->msg_iov;
msg_iovlen = msg->msg_iovlen;
```

Comment: Did the answer help you? Or is there something unclear?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you use Linux kernel >= 3.19. Since 3.19 kernel [`struct msghdr`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.19.8/source/include/linux/socket.h#L47) is divided into `struct msghdr` and `struct user_msghdr`.

Now `struct user_msghdr` containes `msg_iov` and `msg_iovlen`. But **[`struct iov_iter`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.19.8/source/include/linux/uio.h#L28)** must be used instead of `msg_iov` and `msg_iovlen`.

Something like:

```
struct msghdr msg;
struct iovec iov;
iov.iov_base = buffer;
iov.iov_len  = length;

/* fill in msg */

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3,19,0)
msg.msg_iov = &iov;
msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
#else
iov_iter_init(&msg.msg_iter, READ, &iov, 1, length);
#endif

/* ... */
/* call sock_recvmsg() or kernel_recvmsg() */
```

Comment: Kind of them to break working code, and an API that is nearly 40 years old.

Comment: So what is `length` and how to get `msg->msg_iovlen` and `msg->msg_iov`? I'm trying to fix this script: https://superuser.com/a/1560259/464244